# disabling android.mk auto-generated by AS still return ndk-build.cmd finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build

similar question asked many times before, but i tried every solution i found still getting the same error.

**problem** ndk-build fails with non-zero exit value 2

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'.
> Process 'command 'D:\softwares\ndk\android-ndk-r13\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

as i read on forums reason is AS ignore android.mk and auto generate it's own. to disable that sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs = [] to android shoudl be added to gradle. still getting the same error.

i tried many examples nothing works for simplicity [source code](https://www.crystax.net/blog/3)

AS     2.2

GRADLE 2.2

OS     windows 10

Comment: I have same problem 1 month ago....

Comment: Cut Ndk and paste in Root folder like D:\ndk then it can be solved

Comment: and set ndk path in android studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio version 2.2.0 and above supports new native build mechanisms -- cmake and ndk-build, refer to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html). Some samples could be found from [github](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk), ndkBuild samples are also there in directory [other-builds/ndkbuild](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/other-builds/ndkbuild)

windows having 260 characters limitation for file path, you might met problem when building some of the samples under windows, in that case, you could copy the sources and the scripts into the same folder [and close to root directory]. Other OS would build as is.

The version if native support you mentioned is deprecated, new ndkbuild and cmake replace it.